# Solenoidal and irrotational fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I was wondering if there is any possibility that a vector field is irrotational and solenoidal at the same time. Can you help me out? I think I can't see the correct interpretation. I think that if, given a vector field A, it is solenoidal, it can't be irrotational. Could you give me some arguments?

Comment: Well, the $0$ field...

Comment: There’s always the zero vector field that satisfies both but I’m sure that’s not what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, at different scale levels. If your differential operators for one of them is on different part of Fourier frequency spectrum than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a vector field $\vec A$ is irrotational,

$\nabla \times \vec A = 0, \tag 1$

and also solenoidal,

$\nabla \cdot \vec A = 0; \tag 2$

(1) implies the existence of a function $\phi$ such that

$\vec A = \nabla \phi; \tag 3$

then by (2),

$\nabla^2 \phi = \nabla \cdot \nabla \phi = \nabla \cdot \vec A = 0; \tag 4$

$\phi$ is thus a *harmonic function*; we thus see that a field satisfying (1) and (2) is the gradient of some harmonic $\phi$; conversely, if (3) binds for some harmonic $\phi$, then

$\nabla \cdot \vec A = \nabla \cdot \nabla \phi = \nabla^2 \phi = 0, \tag{5}$

and

$\nabla \times \vec A = \nabla \times \nabla \phi = 0, \tag{6}$

identically.

We thus see that the class of irrotational, solenoidal vector fields conicides, locally at least, with the class of gradients of harmonic functions.

Such fields are prevalent in *electrostatics*, in which the Maxwell equation

$\nabla \times \vec E = -\dfrac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t} \tag 7$

becomes

$\nabla \times \vec E = 0 \tag{8}$

in the event that the magnetic field $\vec B$ is constant in time; the in the absence of charges, e.g., in free space, the equation

$\nabla \cdot \vec E = \dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \tag 9$

yields

$\nabla \cdot \vec E = 0; \tag{10}$

it thus follows that there exists a (voltage) potential $\phi$ with

$\vec E = \nabla \phi \tag{11}$

and

$\nabla^2 \phi = 0. \tag{12}$

For more, see [this wikipedia page on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field)  conservative vector fields, as well as this one on [solenoidal fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field).